# Create complex types (definitions) in Swagger

Tags: yaml, swagger, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

I created a definition called `Product` and another called `Text` (see code).

On `parameters` of `paths` I can not use the type `Text` created in definitions. On the definition `Product` I have a property called `message` and I want that property to be the type `Text` too.

```
(...)

paths:
  /products:
    get:
      summary: Product Types
      description: |
        Description text
      parameters:
        - name: latitude
          in: query
          description: Latitude component of location.
          required: true
          ### The type Text was not found here
          type: Text ### The type Text was not found here
(...)

definitions:

  Product:
    properties:
      message:
        ### The type Text was not found here
        type: Text ### Compilation Error in this line ####
      name:
        type: string
        description: Data description.


  Text:
    properties:
      code:
        type: string
```

But this error occurs:

> Swagger Error:
>   Data does not match any schemas from 'anyOf'.

How can I reference the type `Text` on the type `Product`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use `$ref` instead. Here is an example

```
type: object
required:
- name
properties:
  name:
    type: string
  address:
    $ref: '#/definitions/Address'
  age:
    type: integer
    format: int32
    minimum: 0
```

Ref: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#simple-model

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer... It works for this example, but now I cant using $ref inside of paths parameters. I put the example above. Do you know how to reference this type inside parameters of paths? Regards.

Comment: For path parameter, you cannot use `model`. Path parameter should be of primitive type, e.g. string, number, etc.